# Parse Soapui xml response

Tags: xml, soapui

**XML example:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    .....
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using below script to traverse

```
def authorResult=soapenv:Envelope;
```

it is throwing error that "found':'

Answer (score 0):

You can access for XMl response by 2 solution.

#### Solution 1

```
def xml = new groovy.util.XmlParser().parseText('''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:creditCard">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:creditCardResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:creditCard">
            <return xsi:type="tns:RPResponse">
                <Status xsi:type="xsd:int">111</Status>
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">BBBB</Value>
            </return>
        </ns1:creditCardResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
''')

// XXX namespaces quoted
assert xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Status.text()=='111'
log.info xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Status.text()
assert xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Value.text()=='BBBB'
log.info xml.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Value.text()
```

#### Solution 2

```
def xml = new groovy.util.XmlParser().parseText('''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:creditCard">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:creditCardResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:creditCard">
            <return xsi:type="tns:RPResponse">
                <Status xsi:type="xsd:int">111</Status>
                <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">BBBB</Value>
            </return>
        </ns1:creditCardResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
''')
    // XXX access by namespace
    def nsSoapEnv = new groovy.xml.Namespace('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'SOAP-ENV')
    def nsNs1 = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:creditCard', 'ns1')
    assert xml[nsSoapEnv.Body][nsNs1.creditCardResponse].return.Status.text()=='111'
    assert xml[nsSoapEnv.Body][nsNs1.creditCardResponse].return.Value.text()=='BBBB'
```

Please you can review this post.[Read xml values in namespaces/SOAP response using groovy XMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28107371/7324872)